# Fair die - probability - geometric

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, dice

Throw a fair die.
X is the number of throws until the first appearance of 6, Y is the number of throws until the first appearance of 5.

I need to calculate E(x), so I used geometric expectency (1/1/6) = 6

Now, I need to calculate -

[image: how i do it?]

Comment: what have you tried ? where are you stuck ? [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: I think i don't know how to do Conditional expectation on Discrete random variable. I know on Continuous random variable, because it's integral. but here, I dont know what I need to put in the counter, in the denominator, I know I need to put p(y) = 1/6

Comment: $\mathbb E[X\mid Y=1]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P\{Y=1\}}\sum_{i=1}^6 i\mathbb P\{X=i,Y=1\}=\sum_{i=1}^6i\mathbb P\{X=i\mid Y=1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$E(X|Y=1)$$

means that the first die roll is 5

thus

$$E(X|Y=1)=1+6=7$$

Comment: can you explain to me? I dont understand the calculate

Comment: @user123 it is the same geometric distribution but with support $\{2,3,4,...\}$ that is the same as calculating $E(X+1)=E(X)+1)$. If my answer has been useful you can accept it

Comment: so for E(X/Y=5) we need to do 5+6 = 11 ?

Comment: @user123 no, I did not say that. But think that in the first 4 rolls, no #5 appeared

Comment: so I don't understand...

Comment: any explain plese?

Comment: any help?.......

Comment: can you explain me your calculate?

Comment: @user  take care of this hint: if the first 6 does not apper in the first 4 rolls (and this happens with a certain probability) the expectation is $5+6$. If the first 6 appears at first roll, the expectation is 1...and so on. Concluding, your expectation will be an average of these numbers

Comment: but in Discrete random variables that happend -  E(X|Y=y)=E(X) no?

Comment: any help about it?